# Why does my fresh Debian have a high latency?

Tags: debian, performance

The time between clicking and seeing a response is very high. Typing looks very funny, and makes me feel queasy. I think there's about 50-20ms "extra". I would expect a top notch linux distro to have a really good response time, so what's up with this?

System specs are sufficient (AMD FX-8150, HD7800, ASRock 970 Pro3 R2, Samsung 840 128GB). The delay was there since install (Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (wheezy), netinstall). I thought a videocard driver would help. Installing fglrx (as per https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) did not help at the delay. It did make everything much more graphical, which is nice.

Any thoughts?

dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/FDqJQ7mK
lspci output: http://pastebin.com/SaHjr4J0

Comment: have you tried running other distro from USB/CD? If it is a Debian issue, those should maybe boot slower, but not feel as sluggish as you describe.

Comment: Run `iotop`, which shows disk activity. Disk activity may be a contributory cause in slowing the system down.

Comment: iotop shows that the skies are clear (no disk IO). I ran Ubuntu XFCE and got burned out over a disturbing plenty of minor issues.

Comment: I already feel a lot less weird using the desktop. It still responds slower than it could but I'm not certain it is a misconfiguration issue. How much delay should I expect?

Comment: There shouldn't be any delay when typing.  It's probably not misconfiguration, it is more likely some kind of driver bug.  This is even more likely if you've also had problems with a live CD from another distro.